# Record a video using Webcam with raspberrypi

Tags: video, raspberry-pi, timestamp, webcam, video-recording

anyone can help? I am going to to record a video using webcam and raspberry pi. I need to display the timestamp inside the video when the video starting until the end.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know which operating system that you want to use.

- In case you are using Raspbian try: **video4linux2** .
- In case you are using Windows IoT you can get your information
  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/camera).